# I got +1 rep for removed post

Tags: support, reputation

I got +1 reputation for removed post, Is this normal or bug ? see my [reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220577/bala?tab=reputation).

AFAIK for removed post I will get -2 rep, It because of I made suggested edit to that post.

> [image]

Also with notification

[image]

Comment: Can you give a link of that post?

Comment: @hims056 I can't give, because it is removed, I think only 10K users can access. I will post image.

Comment: oooooo... you might want to block out your personal(?) email address from the screenshot :)

Comment: @Lix no its not my personal, you can check my profile page, its public.

Comment: It might not be personal - but it is not publically visible on the site. Only devs/mods can see it - and even still - it's on a per request basis (they have to click "show" to see it).

Comment: @Lix really thanks !!!.

Comment: @Bala - glad to help :)

Comment: @hims056 [here it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202804/152859) - the question still exists, only the answer (which indeed has one downvote) was deleted by its owner recently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you downvote someone, they get 2 reputation points taken away and you (as the voter) also get 1 reputation point removed.

What happened here is that the post you downvoted was removed, so the -1 that you got was reverted, hence +1.

---

If the action you took on the post was a suggested edit, the same procedure will happen. You get +2 reputation points for the edit, then when the post is removed, you would get -2 reputation points.

Comment: Is it also possible that he posted an answer, got 1 vote up(+5) and 3 downvotes(-6) and the question got deleted(+1)?

Comment: @Loko - yes. This is also possible, but all of those upvotes and downvotes would have also added entries into the reputation breakdown. Perhaps we simply can't see them because they happened on previous days.

Comment: @Loko More likely that s/he posted a question, got 14 downvotes (-28), 3 upvotes (+15), posted an answer which got 1 upvote (+10) and accepted someone else's answer (+2), then deleted the question.

Comment: @JDB What about an answer with 8 downvotes(-16),2 upvotes(+15) on a question he editted (+2), which he downvoted (-1) and he downvoted someone elses answer(-1) and then the question got deleted? Seems more logic

Comment: @Loko OK, you win. :)

Comment: @JDB https://www.pinterest.com/pin/485333297313210067/

Comment: @Loko Why down vote ? really don't know why people use down vote without comment, and I'm asked only the proper question here, really I hate down voters without comment for proper question. they are really a....

Comment: @Bala Why are you asking me? I didn't downvote.

Comment: @Loko sorry for that