# Title vanishes when editing a question

Tags: bug, edits, specific-question, title

While trying to edit [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212997/how-can-there-be-no-users-with-the-ip-of-a-user) I noticed the title vanished:

> [image]

This is for inline edit, in the [edit page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/212997/edit) there's no title and no tags as well.

Most likely the cause is the first revision of that question hard deleted as can be seen in the [revisions list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/212997/revisions), but still I'd like to get title and tags back when editing.

Comment: Interesting! I don't know that I've noticed this before. I wonder if it's a new bug?

Comment: @WendiKidd it's an edge case, most likely caused by hard deleting the first revision after the post was edited. It's not easy to reproduce, actually only a dev or community manager can repro this one.

Comment: Repro'd on that question (you linked)!

Comment: @ShadowWizard also the case for [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210174/i-got-1-rep-for-removed-post) which also had its first revision nuked.  Good spot!

Comment: Cheers @Rory and nice find! :)